# Form calculator based on input values

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, calculator

I am working on a Cardio Test calculator which calculates heart attack risk. I want to get score based value for each input. The results logic is already working, I just need to get result score value. See the code below.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#female").change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $("#femaleage").show();
      $("#maleage").hide();
    }
  });

  $("#male").change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $("#maleage").show();
      $("#femaleage").hide();
    }
  });

  $( "#cardio__test" ).submit(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($("#score").val() <= 3) {
      $(".risk__score.low__risk").show();
    } 

    if ($("#score").val() >= 4 && $("#score").val() <= 6) {
      $(".risk__score.moderate__risk").show();
    }

    if ($("#score").val() >= 7) {
      $(".risk__score.high__risk").show();
    }

    if ($("#maleage").val() >= 70) {
      $("#score").val() + 8;
    }

    $(this).hide();
  });



});

</script>
```

Here's [a link](https://codepen.io/samarkandiy/pen/MqGPpp)!

Answer (score 0):

I tested out your codepen and I found out the value of your score is a *string* type instead of *int* as I tested using `parseInt()` and `typeof`... and the result string value is blank (maybe i changed some code in the codepen during testing) How do you check the value of the **score** and do you get it as a *number*?
 Anyway, to print out the result value you can do it in many ways such as

- adding a new `div` in your *results* div and print the results inside the div

  `$(".(new div class name) h3").text($("#score").val());`
- or simply alert the results

  `alert($("#score").val());`

Comment: Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use

```
var scoreValue = $("#score").val();
```